# Actor responding to another InputListerner

Tags: android, libgdx, scene2d

Say if I had an Actor that is responding to InputListener

How to stop this actor from responding to another InputListener until the previous one is finished

I have the following classes :

class MyActor

```
public class MyActor extends Image {
    public MyActor() {
        super(new Texture("img.png"));
        setPosition(100, 100);
        debug();
    }
}
```

class TestScreen

```
public class TestScreen implements Screen {
    GameMain gameMain;
    Stage stage;
    MyActor myActor;

    public TestScreen(GameMain gameMain) {
        this.gameMain = gameMain;
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        stage = new Stage();
        myActor = new MyActor();

        //addlistener to actor
        myActor.addListener(new InputListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                RotateByAction rba = new RotateByAction();
                rba.setAmount(90.0f);
                rba.setDuration(3.0f);
                myActor.addAction(rba);
                System.out.println("actor is rotating");
                return true;
            }
        });
        stage.addActor(myActor);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        stage.act(delta);
        stage.draw();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actor has a getActions() method that lists all current actions. Once an action has finished, it is removed from the Actor. Before allowing your actor to respond to other listener events, check the actor's current actions and make your determination from there. (ie, if your actor still has the previous action then "ignore" the listener's events)

You can also create sequence actions, which are 2 or more actions to be executed consecutively. The 2nd (or last) action could be a RunnableAction and in it's run() method you give further instructions to your Actor (eg: "OK to accept new events"). This second option is kind of like a callback when the other actions have finished.

Comment: ok but actually I am not using actions when actor is touched I write it as an example
myactor do some other stuff to other actors when it is touched

Comment: Not sure I understand fully. But if you have ActorA, which onTouch() instructs ActorB, C, D ... to do things and you want B, C, D to be finished before ActorA on Touch() send more to them? Then some sort of callback would still be appropriate. B, C, D would have to notify A they are done, and A would have to track that before passing on new events to them. Java's observer/observable pattern might work. A implements the Observer interface and B, C, D are Observable(s) that notify A of a change (in this case, notify on done).